# yum install git on RHEL 6.7 (Santiago) fails with missing perl dependency

Tags: linux, installation, git, yum

I am trying to install git using yum package manager on a linux VM Red Hat Enterprise v6.7 (Santiago) and I run unfortunately into the following issue after I run : yum install git

Error Package: git222-perl-Git-2.22.0-2.el6.ius.noarch (ius)
    Requires: perl (Error)

note that perl already exists on that system:

$ which perl
$ /usr/bin/perl

Any clues as to how to workaround this would be highly appreciated !

Best Regards,
Claudio

Comment: i was able to workaround this issue by installing via yum the following perl module: [root@europa-16 ~]# yum list | grep "perl.*Error"
perl-Error.noarch                        1:0.17015-4.el6          @/perl-Error-0.17015-4.el6.noarch

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 6.7 was released 2015-07-22, over five years ago. git222 from IUS is built against the latest version of RHEL (and all included perl libraries), which is currently RHEL 6.10. On an up to date system, installing git222-perl-Git works just fine, as yum is able to resolve the `perl(Error)` requirement with the perl-Error package.  Fully updating your system should resolve this for you.